# Python GrayCode saved as string directly to decimal

Tags: python, validation, integer, converters, gray-code

Im working for a python project and i wonder if the following is possible:

Currently I have a graycode stored as an string i.e: "1000" and I want to convert it to is integer (decimal, base10) value --> 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RosettaCode](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Gray_code#Python):

```
def gray_decode(n):
    m = n >> 1
    while m:
        n ^= m
        m >>= 1
    return n
```

This takes an `int` as input, so you would have to parse the string before calling the function:

```
a = "1000"
print(gray_decode(int(a, 2)))
```

Comment: `gray_decode(int(a))` is wrong. it needs to be `gray_decode(int(a, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

The following table shows the conversion of binary code values to gray code values:

| Decimal Value | Binary Equivalent | Gray Code Equivalent | Decimal Value of Gray Code Equivalent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 000 | 000 | 0 |
| 1 | 001 | 001 | 1 |
| 2 | 010 | 011 | 3 |
| 3 | 011 | 010 | 2 |
| 4 | 100 | 110 | 6 |
| 5 | 101 | 111 | 7 |
| 6 | 110 | 101 | 5 |
| 7 | 111 | 100 | 4 |

Try this code

#### FROM DECIMAL TO GRAY CODE

```py
def grayCode(n):
     
    # Right Shift the number
    # by 1 taking xor with
    # original number
    return n ^ (n >> 1)
 
 
# Driver Code
n = "1000"
print(grayCode(int(n)))
```

#### FROM GRAY CODE TO DECIMAL

```py
def inversegrayCode(n):
    inv = 0;
     
    # Taking xor until
    # n becomes zero
    while(n):
        inv = inv ^ n;
        n = n >> 1;
    return inv;
 
# Driver Code
n = "15";
print(inversegrayCode(int(n)));
```

source : [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decimal-equivalent-gray-code-inverse/)

Answer (score 0):

there is a good example [here](https://www.sanfoundry.com/python-program-convert-gray-code-binary)
the gist is:

```
n = '1000'
n = int(n, 2) # convert to int
 
mask = n
while mask != 0:
    mask >>= 1
    n ^= mask
```